# How to remove a parameter set in an alias from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, parameters

I have an alias for "ls" set like this:

```
alias ls='ls -lh'
```

If at some point I wanted to perform a one-time regular ls without either of those parameters (without l or without h), how would I do that without changing the alias?

I tried ls !l, ls -!l and ls --l but those don't work. Is there a syntax for negating a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias replaces one *string* with another *string*. It's a simple replacement before processing the line further. If the alias is

```
alias ls='ls -lh'
```

then `ls` at the beginning of the line will be replaced by `ls -lh`. Period.

If `ls` itself provided some syntax for negating an option, so a later option could override what's in front, then you could do this. With some options you can, e.g.:

```
ls --color=yes --color=no
```

If `ls` was aliased to `ls --color=yes` and you typed `ls --color=no`, then the actual command would include both options and the typed one would win, because this is how `ls` parses and understands its options. But you cannot make an option like `-l` just disappear. If the alias makes it appear then it's there.

Some tools may provide options that contradict each other and the last one wins; or the first one wins. Some tools may provide a way to negate almost any of their options (e.g. `--foo` vs. `--no-foo`; `--bar` vs. `--no-bar`). It's always up to the tool and there is no widespread convention, as far as I know.

You may [not use alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39296/108618):

```
\ls
command ls
/bin/ls
"ls"
'ls'
```

Each of these will not trigger the alias, so you can append your desired set of options.

In Bash you can expand the line before you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The default binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. This makes the following possible:

1. Type `ls`.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, you will see your alias expanded.
3. Edit the line and remove the unwanted option.
4. Prepend `\`, so the alias will not be expanded again after the next step.
5. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute.

Other shells may provide similar functionality.

With the particular alias in question this is not very spectacular because you can type the desired command easily by hand. With a complex alias it may be very useful: you edit a bit instead of typing everything anew.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. I think I'll opt to type \ls when I don't want to display a long list. Losing the -h parameter as well is OK because a short list doesn't include file size anyway.