# Tab doesn't expand the path when using $_ to access the previously typed path

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, zsh, tab-completion

Consider the following scenario:

I've used `ls` to list the contents of a directory, and I've used <kbd>Tab</kbd> to find the right directory, so I don't know the full path. And it's a potentially long path, so I don't want to type it again. Now I'm trying to choose and, for example, copy a single file from that directory into another directory. But to choose the file, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality doesn't work after I've typed `$_`.

As an example,

[image]

I'm trying use to <kbd>Tab</kbd> so that it suggests the contents of a directory, but it doesn't work after I've typed `cp $_/`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `zsh`

When you type `cp $_Tab` (note there is neither space nor `/` after `_`), the shell is able to expand `$_`; but most likely there are more variables that start with `_` and the shell cannot be sure you're not after one of them; therefore you will get a list of variables (try it). To expand `$_` immediately you need to inform the shell the name of the variable/parameter is already complete:

`cp ${_}Tab`

The braces work in a similar way as in `${foo}bar`. You explicitly terminate the name with `}` so whatever follows (e.g. `bar`) is not a part of it. In case of `${_}` the shell understands there is no missing (i.e. yet to be typed) part of the name so `${_}` means `$_` for sure and it can be expanded as such.

After `${_}` gets expanded, the experience with <kbd>Tab</kbd> should be as you expect.

---

#### `bash`

<sup>(Originally the question was tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and I answered accordingly. The tag is no more but I decided to keep this part.)</sup>

After you type `cp $_`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to expand the special parameter. After it's expanded, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will work.

Note the keystroke expands more than variables and parameters. E.g. if your `cp` is an alias then it will be expanded as well. The expanded line will be *expanded again* (if applicable) when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In some circumstances such double expansion may be undesired. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1504806/432690), the part where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> is mentioned.